# Active record interface in ruby for group by and having

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a table with columns id and a1.

`id  a1
1   b2
1   b1
2   b1
1   b3
2   b2`

The query in sql would be -

```
select id, count(*) as TOTAL from table where a1 in (b1, b2) group by(id, a1) having count(*) > 1
```

I have to write this query in record interface -

```
Table.select(:id).where(:a1 => 'b1').group(:id, :a1).count.having(count>1)
```

I am getting the following error -

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `count' for main:Object
```

How can I resolve this error.

**NOTE** - 
I have to include a1 = b1 or a1 = b2 in where, but since I was getting an error in that as well, I removed it.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to pass it like this:

```
Table.select(:id).where(:a1 => 'b1').group(:id, :a1).having('count(*) > 1')
```

Or Even better:

```
Table.select(:id).where(:a1 => 'b1').group(:id, :a1).having('count(*) > ?', 1)
```

Ref: [#Having](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#having)

Another thing, you cannot have `group(:id, :a1).count.having` cause `count` returns a Hash not a `ActiveRecord::Relation`.

Comment: How can I get count(*) and print it's value?

Comment: You can simply call `#size` or `#count` after `Table.select(:id).where(:a1 => 'b1').group(:id, :a1).having('count(*) > ?', 1)`.